# Can a unary functor have member variables?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, boost

I want to use two pieces of the boost library to perform a task, and I'm unsure how to proceed.

I have a line of code for a function, it gives me an answer given the values of N, x and B:

`double ans = cdf(boost::math::binomial mybinom(N, x), B);`

Let's represent this as ans = f(B,N,x).

I want to find the root of this i.e. a value of x at which a function e.g. y = f(x), results in y = 0.

My code, in the form y = f(B,N,x) involves a small rearrangement to negate ans:

```
double myfun = function(B, N, x, ans){
    double output = (cdf(boost::math::binomial mybinom(N, x), B) - ans);
    return output;
}
```

so far so good. Now I know in Boost that the algorithms in the root header will help us find the root, so upon reading I see that TOMS Algorithm 748, will accept as it's main argument 'f' a unary functor. An example is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


#include <boost/math/tools/roots.hpp>

class Test {
public:
    double operator()(const double x) {
        return x * cos(x);
    }
};

// see: 
// http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/toolkit/internals1/roots2.html

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Test t;
    typedef std::pair<double, double> Result;
    boost::uintmax_t max_iter=500;
    boost::math::tools::eps_tolerance<double> tol(30);

    Result r1 = boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(t, 1.0, 2.0, tol, max_iter);
    std::cout << "root bracketed: [ " << r1.first << " , " << r1.second <<  " ]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f("<< r1.first << ")=" << t(r1.first) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f("<< r1.second << ")=" << t(r1.second) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "max_iter=" << max_iter << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, now I hit a problem. Every example I see (for this and similar algorithms) need a unary functor. And show a function with only x as it's argument e.g. `x * cos(x)`. Yet you see my function has the arguments B,N, x, and ans. So how do I get from f(B,N,x,ans) to a unary functor i.e. f(x) such that the boost algorithms can accept it as input to find the root?

One thing I've thought of is maybe (and I have no idea here because I've never heard of a unary functor until now), from what I gather, unary functors are classes, classes can have functions and variables, so could a unary functor class be designed, so on creation, you provide B and N and ans, the values of which are then member variables, and then the function inside the `double operator()(const double x){}` of the unary functor can utilize B and N and ans since they are member variables and do not need to be provided in the operator, which is therefore unary. So as far as I'm concerned, I'm specifying B and N variables upon object creation, but as far as the boost algorithm and the unary operator is concerned, they are member variables and simply values already available inside the body of the function?

I imagine something like:

```
class Test {
public:
    double operator()(const double x) {
        return (cdf(boost::math::binomial mybinom(N, x), B) - ans);
    }
private:
    int B;
    int N;
    double ans;
};
```

Am I on the right lines here or am I barking up the wrong tree?

**--EDIT--**

Here is the code I've currently produced to try address this issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/distributions/binomial.hpp>
#include <boost/math/tools/roots.hpp>



class MyBinom
{
    public:
        MyBinom(int n, int b, double p);
        double operator()(const double x);

    private:
        int N;
        int B;
        double P;
};


MyBinom::MyBinom(int n, int b, double p)
            : N(n), B(b), P(p)
        {/* Body intentionally empty */}


double MyBinom::operator()(const double x)
{
    boost::math::binomial myBinomial(N, x);
    return (cdf(myBinomial, B) - P);
}



int main()
{
    MyBinom myBinom95(4715, 75, 0.95); // Create the Class with the unary operator.

    boost::uintmax_t max_iter=500; // Set max iterations.

    boost::math::tools::eps_tolerance<double> tol(30); //Set the eps tolerance.

    std::pair<double, double> r1 = boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(myBinom95, 0, 1, tol, max_iter); // use the toms solve algorithm.

    std::cout << "Let's take a look at the root" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "root bracketed: [ " << r1.first << " , " << r1.second <<  " ]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f("<< r1.first << ")=" << myBinom95(r1.first) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f("<< r1.second << ")=" << myBinom95(r1.second) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "max_iter=" << max_iter << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However it does not compile - something to do with a boost header:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o test
In file included from /usr/include/boost/math/tools/roots.hpp:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/detail/igamma_inverse.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:1528,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/beta.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/distributions/binomial.hpp:83,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp: In function 'std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&, const Policy&) [with F = MyBinom, T = int, Tol = boost::math::tools::eps_tolerance<double>, Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>, uintmax_t = long unsigned int]':
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:475:71:   instantiated from 'std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&) [with F = MyBinom, T = int, Tol = boost::math::tools::eps_tolerance<double>, uintmax_t = long unsigned int]'
main.cpp:41:100:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:467:81: error: no matching function for call to 'toms748_solve(MyBinom&, const int&, const int&, double, double, boost::math::tools::eps_tolerance<double>&, uintmax_t&, const boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>&)'
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:467:81: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:283:17: note: template<class F, class T, class Tol, class Policy> std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&, const Policy&)
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:458:24: note: template<class F, class T, class Tol> std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&)
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:464:24: note: template<class F, class T, class Tol, class Policy> std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&, const Policy&)
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:473:24: note: template<class F, class T, class Tol> std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&)
```

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: If you're doing what I think you are you want a class-based manipulator and an overloaded stream insertion operator, not a unary functor. (admittedly, you may not be doing what I think you are). You can also provide your N and B in the constructor for `Test` and continue to use your existing form (which is perilously close to what I first mentioned).

Comment: Your idea is perfectly valid, Unary Functor requires that it must be invocable with a single argument, it doesn't matter if it's a function pointer or a object that holds variables and overload `operator()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is correct:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(int B, int N, int ans) : B(B), N(N), ans(ans) {}

    double operator()(const double x) const {
        return (cdf(boost::math::binomial mybinom(N, x), B) - ans);
    }
private:
    int B;
    int N;
    double ans;
};
```

Note that mostly, Functor are copied, so if you want to retrieve some 'mutable' info (as how many time your functor has been called), you have to pass an extra pointer (an simpler counter will not be enough).

Comment: Hi, thanks, This is similar to what I've done - I've updated the original question with the code I've done as it currently is.